# YARN-Specify Which Application to be Run on Which Nodemanager

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I have a Hadoop YARN cluster including one resourcemanager and 6 nodemanagers. I want to run both Flink and Spark applications on the cluster. So I have two main question about YARN:

1. In case of Spark, Should I install and config Spark on resource manager and each nodemanagers? When I want to submit a Spark application on YARN, in addition to YARN resourcemanager and nodemanagers, should Spark cluster (master and slaves) be run?
2. Can I set YARN such that run Flink in some special nodemanagers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, that depends on whether you're using a packaged Hadoop distribution (like Cloudera CDH, Hortonworks HDP for example) or not.  The distros will likely take care of this.  If you're not using a distribution, you need to consider if you want to run Spark on YARN or Spark stand-alone.

For the second question, you can specify special Node Managers if you are using Capacity Scheduler with the node-labelling feature enabled and if you are using Hadoop 2.6 and higher.

Comment: Thanks alot, I use pure Hadoop and Spark packages. So for my first question I was wondering if I should setup Spark in each nodemanager or not, just installing Spark in edge node(where I issue Spark submit command to YRAN resourcemanager ) suffice?

Comment: I think you should only need the Spark jars on all the Node Managers and Spark installed on the edge node.

Comment: When I submit jar file to YARN from edge node, the resource manager will upload all dependencies to HDFS to be accessible for node managers. It is needed to spark be installed and config on the resource manager and all node managers?

Comment: Did you build/use Spark with YARN enabled?

Comment: Yes, I use Spark pre-build version for Hadoop 2.7